# The searchresults.aspx page is picking up an older version of the master page

Tags: sharepoint, wss, wss-3.0, sharepoint-search, wss-3.0-sp2

We have master page called custom.master.
We changed the master page of the searchresults.aspx page to this master page:

```
MasterPageFile="custom.master"
```

We opened the searchresults.aspx page located in C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\ and edited the page.

Now the problem is other aspx pages that we created are using the same master page. But the searchresults.aspx is rendering an older version of the custom.master master page.

We usually edit the custom.master page using share point designer.

Any idea how it is getting the older version of the master page?
How to update the older version of the master page to reflect the new changes that is available in the custom.master page?

Comment: The searchresult.aspx page is located in C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\
So I guess this is an application page.
I think we need to edit a master page for the application pages in this case. That is yet to be found... :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the pages. Master pages for both the site pages and application pages are listed on the _catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx page on the site.

One master page can be found in the Sharepoint designer (after connecting to the site) and the other one is located in the C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\ folder.